# Issue with to_char in sqlplus

Tags: sql, oracle

When I try to use a query like below it does not give me any output . its oracle 8i client connecting to 10g database.

```
SQL> SELECT (to_char(sysdate,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) from dual;

(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'M
-------------------


SQL>
```

Also, a query without the to_char function works without any issues.
When I use the same command in another 8i client connecting to 10g, its working fine. 
I compared the SQL session settings and they look same.

any inputs on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you verify this for me? Is the 10g db the SAME database being accessed from two DIFFERENT 8i clients? Further, any particular reason why the client hasn't been moved to 10g? (probably compatibility, but always a good question.) Finally, what do you get when you SELECT COUNT(1) FROM DUAL? (The correct answer is "1")

Comment: Out of curiousity -- try `SELECT dump(to_char(SYSDATE,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) FROM dual;`  Does it return `NULL` or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Check the dates and crc checksums on the client executables. I'd suspect one is an old version with a bug. You don't give the underlying platforms of the different clients, so it may be a bug that was/is present in (for example) Windows but not *nix

Do you use an 'odd' character set on the client. There could be some unwanted character set conversion.

Why are you using an 8i client ?

An upgrade to a new client (eg the [Database Express Edition client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/express-edition/downloads/102xewinsoft-090667.html)) might be appropriate.

What do you get if you try to select a straight VARCHAR2 variable (eg `SELECT DUMMY FROM DUAL`)

PS. Community wiki so anyone can add suggestions and code snippets

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT to_char(sysdate,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as formmated_date from dual;
```

Comment: thanks but still no luck:" it shows the same thing SQL> SELECT to_char(sysdate,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as formmated_date from dual;

FORMMATED_DATE
-------------------


SQL>

Comment: What happens if you just run select to_char(sysdate, 'MM') as current_month from dual; ?

Comment: When I use to_char , it just gives me blank output as like below                                                                    SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'MM') as current_month from dual;
but when i give select sysdate from dual. it gives me the output:           I believe its a prolem with the t-_char or some formatting for this client only but not sure what to check.. Thanks
CU
--


SQL> select to_char(sysdate) as current_month from dual;

CURRENT_MONTH
-------------------


SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
---------
02-AUG-11

SQL>

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, what do you get if you do select to_date('19960725','YYYYMMDD') as random_date from dual;?  What about select to_char(to_date('19960725','YYYYMMDD')'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as formmated_date from dual;

Comment: thats ok.. below is the output                                                        SQL> select to_date('19960725','YYYYMMDD') as random_date from dual;


RANDOM_DA
---------
25-JUL-96

SQL> SQL> select to_char(to_date('19960725','YYYYMMDD'),'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as formmated_date from dual;

FORMMATED_DATE
-------------------


SQL>